# type [String: String] does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsstring, firebase

I am trying to create a new path called `USERSLIST` in my JSON structure! it will have the list of users that have created account in my firebase app. and in my JSON it must look like this :

> USERSLIST:
>
> - simpleLogin6 : aa@gmail.com
> - simpleLogin9 : bb@gmail.com

it should have the `uid` of the account created as the key and email as the value.

I wrote this code :

```
var usersList = [self.ref.authData.uid : authData.providerData["email"] as? NSString as? String,]
self.ref.childByAppendingPath("userList").childByAutoId().setValue(usersList)
```

But it shows an error in the `setValue` line code that :

```
type [String: String] does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

Comment: What is the type of `authData`? Can you please show us more code to understand all variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var userList  = [String:String]()
if let strEmail = authData.providerData["email"] {

    usersList[self.ref.authData.uid] = strEmail as! String

}
```

Comment: doing some changes in your code the userList is being updated the code is running but the problem is that every time any other user logs in the uid and email are replaced not added.. i want the structure to hold a list of users created ..

Comment: it should not replace the child created but add more childs to the list as they create account @chetan prajapati

Comment: this is what my code looks like for creating the userlist ! 

var userList : [String: String]?

                            if let strEmail: AnyObject = authData.providerData["email"] {
                                
                                userList = [self.ref.authData.uid : strEmail as String]
                                
                            }
self.ref.childByAppendingPath("userList").setValue(userList)



@chetan prajapati

Comment: every time key(self.ref.authData.uid) is defferent? or same for all email address

Comment: yes bcoz a new user creates account by childByautoID @chetan Prajapati it is different for all email addresses

Comment: data in dict like
{
001 : abc@gmail.com,
002 : xyz@gmail.com
}

Comment: usersList[self.ref.authData.uid] = strEmail as! String

Comment: where should i right this ?? help me ! i m confused

Comment: var userList  = [String:String]()
if let strEmail = authData.providerData["email"] {

    usersList[self.ref.authData.uid] = strEmail as! String

}

Comment: i used your code but still every time the new user creates account the old one is replaced by its uid and email.. @chetan

Comment: var userList  = [String:String]() make this is as a global variable

Comment: or create NSUserDefaults for this and maintain this as you want